# Package for encrypt in dart

Tags: dart, security, encryption, rsa

I have a project running on dart version 1.24.3 and I want to encrypt the data using RSA and I couldnt find the package that supports my current dart version what do i do ?

I tried searching the encrypt packages but I found that the minimum version of dart that support encrypt package is 2.0 and mine is 1.24.3

Comment: Any possibility of upgrading to a newer version of Dart? The 1.24.3 version was released "18. dec. 2017" and is therefore extremely old. If you can't upgrade, I would suggest doing the encryption using some external tools you call with the `Process` class to spawn an external process that can then handle the task.

Comment: Pointycastle certainly goes back to Dart 1.x days... https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/commit/30f334efdca3d2b1e677229b14ba0f850930dc09